# Converting Mercurial Repository To Sub Version (SVN)

Tags: svn, version-control, mercurial

This may seem like a very strange situation.

Initially we were using subversion (SVN) for version control...

then we moved to mercurial and used a tool to convert our previous commits to a mercurial form.

And now we want to move back to sub version however we can't seem to find anything that will allow us to keep out history from the mercurial commits and keep them in subversion form.

Does anyone know if this is possible/ how to go about doing it?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, make sure that's what you want to do!  Read this most excellent article about why the philosophy of DVCSes might be better than that of Subversion:

http://www.joelonsoftware.com/items/2010/03/17.html

I don't know whether you'll agree with Joel or not, but you should consider that there are more modern approaches to the subject than Subversion's "CVS without the suck" model.

Is the problem the decentralized nature or the differences with how it works?

If it's the former, this page has some discussion of using Mercurial with a "single central repository."

http://hgbook.red-bean.com/read/collaborating-with-other-people.html

If it's the latter, I hope you'll all give it some more time.  The reasons you migrated in the first place are probably still valid.

Unfortunately, I can't find *any* discussion at all about people migrating from Mercurial to Subversion.  You might need to hack together the equivalent of a Subversion dumpfile (like the output of cvs2svn).

You should probably discuss this with users@subversion.apache.org:

http://subversion.apache.org/mailing-lists.html

That's probably the best place to troll around for advice (or maybe even a script) for doing what you want.